# Angular 2 with *ngFor and ngIf to hide first element

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

In Angular 2,  I got a list of items and based on a given condition (i.e based on location number) I am setting the list to repeat.

I need to hide the "**remove text**" for the first box each location.

**Plunker:**
https://plnkr.co/edit/xtX5BjTBjO61sD2tLwWN?p=preview:

[image: actual img]

```
[1]: https://plnkr.co/edit/xtX5BjTBjO61sD2tLwWN?p=preview
```

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app',
 template: `
   
    <ul *ngFor="let locdata of locations">
   
     <template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items"; let-i=index>
          <div *ngIf="item.location==locdata.location">
             <div class="title"> location  {{ item.location}} <span  *ngIf="isNotFirst(item)">  remove </span> </div>
          <div class="container"> {{ item.sedule}}</div>
       </div>
      </template>
   </ul>
  
 `
})
export class App {
  items: string[];
  
   isNotFirst(item: any) {
      return this.items.filter(i => i.location === item.location).map(i => i.id).indexOf(item.id) !== 0;
    }
  
  locations:any;
  
  constructor() {
    this.locations=[{location:1},{location:2},{location:3}]; 
    
    this.items = [{
    id:1,
    location:1,
    sedule:1
  },
  {
    id:2,
    location:2,
    sedule:1
  },
  {
    id:3,
    location:1,
    sedule:2
  },
  {
    id:4,
    location:2,
    sedule:2
  },
  {
    id:5,
    location:1,
    sedule:2
  },
  {
    id:6,
    location:2,
    sedule:3
  },  {
    id:7,
    location:3,
    sedule:1
  },
  {
    id:8,
    location:3,
    sedule:2
  },
  {
    id:9,
    location:3,
    sedule:3
  }];
  }
  
}
```

Comment: I guess you could add a class to the `first` element and hide it via CSS? (see: http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-ngfor/)

Comment: how will you add that logic I am not able to get.

Comment: we can use the [hidden] also for that but [hidden]= condition not able to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app',
 template: `
   
    <ul *ngFor="let locdata of locations">
   
     <template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items"; let-i=index>
          <div *ngIf="item.location==locdata.location">
             <div class="title"> location  {{ item.location}} <span  *ngIf="isNotFirst(item)">  remove </span> </div>
          <div class="container"> {{ item.sedule}}</div>
       </div>
      </template>
   </ul>
  
 `
})
export class App {
  items: string[];
  
   isNotFirst(item: any) {
      return this.items.filter(i => i.location === item.location).map(i => i.id).indexOf(item.id) !== 0;
    }
  
  locations:any;
  
  constructor() {
    this.locations=[{location:1},{location:2},{location:3}]; 
    
    this.items = [{
    id:1,
    location:1,
    sedule:1
  },
  {
    id:2,
    location:2,
    sedule:1
  },
  {
    id:3,
    location:1,
    sedule:2
  },
  {
    id:4,
    location:2,
    sedule:2
  },
  {
    id:5,
    location:1,
    sedule:2
  },
  {
    id:6,
    location:2,
    sedule:3
  },  {
    id:7,
    location:3,
    sedule:1
  },
  {
    id:8,
    location:3,
    sedule:2
  },
  {
    id:9,
    location:3,
    sedule:3
  }];
  }
  
}
```

Comment: you don't need let-i=index anymore.

Comment: `template ` is deprecated in Angular4. Use `ng-template`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 8):

assume you have a `<span>` in `*ngFor` logic,  you can use `first` from `*ngFor` and show/hide `<span>` by `*ngIf`

```
<div *ngFor="let item in data; let first=first;">
  {{item.attr}}
  <span *ngIf="!first">
    remove
  </span>
</div>
```

your working **[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Cw0wOZVdm8N8cmiMEpIu)**.

Comment: please check the plnkr code you will get the main requirement

Comment: @B.V.SBharatKumar check the plunker at my answer.

Comment: for location 2 it removed but for location 1 list it did not

Comment: please check the link once: we got two location plnkr.co/edit/lu37lt6Y9pe5dlOxXEZx?p=preview –

Comment: @B.V.SBharatKumar let me check.  wait a moment please.

Comment: @B.V.SBharatKumar the second one doesn't first for it's not the first element in ngFor.   you may consider adding specific `index` for different locations at your `items` or create a custom pipe.

Comment: @B.V.SBharatKumar check the plunker again, I have build a simple pipe for you to achieve hat you want. hope it helps :)

Comment: please check we need to hide remove for each location https://plnkr.co/edit/xtX5BjTBjO61sD2tLwWN?p=preview

Comment: @B.V.SBharatKumar did the newest plunker meet what you want? if not, please let me know. :)

Answer (score 2):

After doing some deciphering of your template, I think that your basic html for a single item in your items collection looks like:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
      <h4>Syntax 1</h4>
       <div>
          <div class="title"> 
             location  {{ item.location}} 
             <span *ngIf="true">remove</span> 
          </div>
          <div class="container">
             {{ item.sedule}}
          </div>
        </div>
    `
})
export class App { .... }
```

If that's your basic template for a single item, you can then use *ngFor stamp out multiple versions of this HTML, one for each item in your `items` collection.

That gives you a template that looks like:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
      <h4>Syntax 1</h4>
       <div *ngFor="let item of items">
          <div class="title"> 
             location  {{ item.location}} 
             <span *ngIf="true">remove</span> 
          </div>
          <div class="container">
             {{ item.sedule}}
          </div>
        </div>
    `
})
export class App { .... }
```

The final piece to the puzzle is that you only want to show the `remove` text for a specific item in the collection - namely the first item. Thankfully, `ngFor` has a solution to this very same problem - you can ask `ngFor` to tell you the index of the current item in the list of items. You can make use of that index to show or hide the 'remove' text. Since the first item will have an index of 0, then your `ngIf` test will test against that value.

That gives you:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
      <h4>Syntax 1</h4>
    <ul>
       <div *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index;">
          <div class="title"> 
             location  {{ item.location}} 
             <span *ngIf="i != 0">remove</span> 
          </div>
          <div class="container">
             {{ item.sedule}}
          </div>
        </div>
    </ul>
    `
})
export class App { .... }
```

Notice the change in the ngFor statement - by using `let i=index`, you're creating a local template variable `i` that will be mapped to the current index of the item being output by `ngFor`. Then you can test against that value to show/hide an element if needed.

(Note that in addition to `index`, `ngFor` provides `first`, `last`, `even` and `odd` variables that you could also make use of. I used `index` in this example because it has the most wide reaching usage, but you could've easily used `first` for this use case.

[See the documentation for more info about ngFor](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html)

Comment: please check we need to hide remove for each location https://plnkr.co/edit/xtX5BjTBjO61sD2tLwWN?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

See here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/nMvnonrBjRfq1n8tmfZT?p=preview

You need condition like:

```
*ngIf="i !== 1"
```

Comment: check this plnkr you will get main idea

Comment: we got two location not single

Comment: please check the link once: we got two location  https://plnkr.co/edit/lu37lt6Y9pe5dlOxXEZx?p=preview

Comment: for that it is *ngIf="i !== 0" https://plnkr.co/edit/28YGcPXWr0QFqFDYcyU4?p=preview

Comment: please check we need to hide remove for each location https://plnkr.co/edit/xtX5BjTBjO61sD2tLwWN?p=preview

Comment: added another answer what you are looking for.